# Subclassed QWidget and mouse events

Tags: c++, qt, mouse

I'm trying to code a widget that utilizes HGE functionality. So I have subclassed from QWidget and overloaded paintEvent(). It works OK but troubles appear when I try to handle input. Events are handled only when mouse enters zone 2([link text](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/335167/qtShit.png)) But I need to handle input in zone 1(where HGE is rendering). What should I do?

Comment: How are you handling input events? Can you add some code?

Comment: Sure. 
http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?8al3o95s73jp

Comment: Did you try with setMouseTracking( true )?

Comment: Yep, I tried. It had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that HGE is rendering in it's own window, which you've put onto your QWidget subclass, and so your widget can't grab the mouse from the other window's area